# How to print data from stringstream to a file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, event-log

I have opened a file using *CreateFile* fn and tried to print data into the file. Since the data includes some print statements like

`wprintf(L"Channel %s was not found.\n", pwsPath);`

The declaration for DATA and pwsPath

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
string data;
LPWSTR pwsPath = L"Channel1";
```

I tried to use stringstream to get the data and convert it to a LPCVOID to use the   *WriteFile*  fn as shown

```
hFile1 = CreateFile(L"MyFile.txt",                // name of the write
                   GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                   0,                      // do not share
                   NULL,                   // default security
                   CREATE_ALWAYS,             // create new file only
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                   NULL); 

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Channel" << pwsPath << "was not found.";

ss >> data;
cout << data; // data contains value only till the first space i.e Channel093902
cin>>data;



         bErrorFlag = WriteFile( 
                hFile1,           // open file handle
                data.c_str(),      // start of data to write
                dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
                &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                NULL);
```

Is it possible for variable  *data* to include spaces from the stringstream ??
OR
Is there any other way other than stringstream to get the data from such print statements and write to the file as such?

Comment: There's [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), but really, `ss.str()` gets the entire thing painlessly. And for something like this, why not `std::string data = std::string("Channel") + pwsPath + "was not found.";`?

Comment: @chris why do we need std::string("channel") can't it be "channel" ? Is there any fn to print the the statement `wprintf(L"Channel %s was not found.\n", pwsPath);` into the string or char array directly

Comment: If `pwsPath` is a C string, it won't work because C strings don't support adding two together. Anyway, there's `boost::format` and others for C++ strings and `sprintf` et al for C strings.

Comment: Can you post data's declaration?

Comment: @MarcoA. its just `string data;`. I have  edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The >> operator will deliver the next 'word' in the stream into the string object you have given it. It breaks at the first white space as you have found. There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want. The most conformant is to open the output file as an ofstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::string pwsPath { "[enter path here]" };
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Channel " << pwsPath << " was not found.";   

    std::ofstream outFile("myFile.txt");
    outFile << ss.rdbuf();
    outFile.close();

    std::ifstream inFile("myFile.txt");
    cout << inFile.rdbuf();

    return 0;
}
```

otherwise you can get the internal string from the ostringstream:

```
std::string myData = ss.str();
size_t dataLength = myData.length();
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
BOOL bErrorFlag = WriteFile( 
                hFile1,           // open file handle
                myData.data(),      // start of data to write
                DWORD(dataLength),  // number of bytes to write
                &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a good reason to use CreateFile and WriteFile, consider using std objects all the way.

Your code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // add this

#include <sstream> // remove this unless used elsewhere

// your pwsPath
std::wstring path{ L"Channel1" };

std::wofstream out{ L"MyFile.txt", std::wofstream::trunc };

// skip the stringstream completely
out << "Channel " << path << " was not found."
```

Comment: Its better if I use CreateFile and WriteFile